# SslNegotiateCert Web.Config Error with Thinktecture.IdentityServer .NET 4.5

Tags: oauth-2.0, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I am using the Thinktecture.IdentityServer (OnPremise) .NET 4.5 version. I need some assistance debugging a configuration issue. When I try to access my OAuth endpoint, I get a

> "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot
>   be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid."

This is the Config Error:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

The Config Source for the problem area in the web.config is:

```
34:       <security>
35:         <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
36:       </security>
```

I am uncertain how to move forward. I tried this solution: http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path/ but no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by going to the IIS Manager > Click on the server root connection > Feature Delegation (Under Management) > Custom Site Delegation... (Under Actions on the right) > Pick the site > Change SSL Settings to Read/Write

More information can be found here: http://davefancher.com/2010/10/29/unlocking-configuration-sections-in-iis-7-x/